# Erro ao fechar executável

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8

Tenho uma aplicação que possui 4 formulários.

Após o processo existe um botão para a pessoa iniciar novamente.

```
procedure TForm4.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
      FreeAndNil(Form1);
      FreeAndNil(Form2);
      FreeAndNil(Form3);
      FreeAndNil(Form4); //Libera o form da memória
      Application.CreateForm(Tform1, form1);
      Application.CreateForm(Tform2, form2);
      Application.CreateForm(Tform3, form3);
      Application.CreateForm(Tform4, form4);
      Application.Run; //Roda a aplicação
end;
```

Até ai ok, mas caso ela aperte no botão de fechar .

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Apresenta a seguinte mensagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ele trava, aparece a mensagem do windows para fechar o programa, e só assim ele fecha.

*obs: (O erro só aparece caso a pessoa clique no botão para iniciar o processo novamente, caso ela abra o programa pela primeira vez, funciona corretamente.)*

Acredito que está com um problema na hora de liberar os forms, aonde posso estar errando?

Minha intenção é que quando clicar no `button3` houvesse um `reset` no form, e o usuário começasse do zero.

Comment: Você no `OnClose` do form tá apagando ele mesmo, mandando recriar, e dando `Application.Run` denovo?

Comment: acredito que não, quando digo clicar no fechar é o da janela mesmo. Não adicionei nenhum evento ao onclose

Comment: O código que você mostrou é o que está no `.dpr` então?

Comment: Exatamente, eu uso ele em um botão.

Comment: Como assim um botão? Pode mostrar mais do código? Tá muito confuso pra mim ainda.

Comment: Vou editar a pergunta amigo.

Comment: Em qual linha acontece o problema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente isso:

```
procedure TForm4.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 if TForm1 = nil then Form1 := TForm1.Create(Application);
 Form1.Show;

 if TForm2 = nil then Form2 := TForm2.Create(Application);
 Form2.Show;

 if TForm3 = nil then Form3 := TForm3.Create(Application);
 Form3.Show;

 if TForm4 = nil then Form4 := TForm4.Create(Application);
 Form4.Show;
end;

// insira no evento OnClose de cada Form1,2,3,4
procedure TForm4.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
 action:=caFree;
 Form4 :=nil;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Na inicialização, a aplicação criou os formulários e guardou referência a eles a fim de poder destruí-los depois, ao ser encerrada.

O código de *Button3Click* destrói os formulários criados pela aplicação, de modo que quando a aplicação tenta destruí-los (durante o encerramento) ela chama o *free* utilizando as referências, agora inválidas, aos formulários que não existem mais, daí o erro.

A solução talvez seja retirar os formulários da lista de inicialização automática, talvez mudar a forma de "iniciar novamente" a aplicação.

Se desejar resetar realmente a aplicação, você pode usar este código: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6020898/1274092. Ele cria uma nova instância da aplicação e encerra a instância corrente em seguida.

Comment: o que quero fazer é que o fluxo continue, como se a aplicação tivesse sido fechada e aberto novamente um "reset" na aplicação.

Comment: @GuilhermeLima Não é informação suficiente. Talvez você deva assumir o fluxo de execução da aplicação, criando e controlando o ciclo de vida dos formulários. A chamada ao *Application.run* em um click de botão também é bem esquisita.

Comment: Concordo, e estou disposto a aceitar uma nova maneira de fazer o que quero, que novamente digo, é basicamente é dar um reset na aplicação.

Comment: @GuilhermeLima Adicionei uma referência que reinicia a aplicação de fato (manda abrir uma nova instância e fecha a instância corrente em seguida).

Comment: Bom notar que esse código de "resetar" a aplicação cria uma nova instância da aplicação, o que impede de usar um debugger na nova instância.

Comment: @DarkHyudrA Não impede não. Usar o botãozinho de depuração não é a única maneira de depurar em Delphi. Você também pode attachar o depurador a um processo existente e também pode indicar um programa que vai executar antes do seu quando você mandar a IDE depurar. E talvez existam ainda outras maneiras que não me lembro mais.

Comment: @Caffé mas pra isso o comando que tu precisa passar pro Shell é diferente. Eu não disse que é impossível, é só que com **aquele** comando, o programa não vai passar pelo depurador do Delphi.

Comment: @DarkHyudrA Bem, acho que não entendi do que você está falando. Apenas não percebo nenhum problema quanto a depuração, tanto da instância corrente quanto da nova instância, é perfeitamente viável e simples depurar qualquer uma delas, em qualquer situação desejável.